# When scrolling in a Menu - Picker, releasing the tap mid-scroll causes it to keep jumping to the top

Tags: swiftui, redraw, observedobject, jump-list, swiftui-picker

```swift
struct PlainTextPicker<T: Hashable>: View
{
    @Binding var selection: T?
    let defaultString: String?
    var options: [T]
    var toLabel: (T) -> String

    // body
    Menu
    { 
        Picker("Select", selection: $selection)
        {
            if let defaultString = defaultString
            {
                 Text(defaultString).tag(nil as T?)
            }
                
            ForEach(options, id:\.self)
            {   option in
                Text(toLabel(option)).tag(option as T?)
            }
        } label: 
        {
            HStack
            {
                Text(getSelectionText())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
PlainTextPicker(selection: $selectedStall, 
                options: ItemsInformation.shared.getItems(customer, category: category),
                defaultString: "Please Select Item",
                toLabel: {"\($0.code) \($0.name)"})
```

In `SwiftUI / iOS 16.4+`, I'm using a Picker as a label in a Menu as shown in the above code. In a specific view, when the total size of the Picker (the area where selections can be made) is larger than the screen and requires scrolling, releasing a tap while scrolling causes the picker to jump to the top.

What I suspect is that redraws are occurring due to changes in specific observable properties. Therefore, I checked for changes in variables that may trigger redraws, such as `@State`, `@ObservedObject`, and `@StateObject`. Additionally, I'm using a Timer, and even when I stop the Timer, the same issue persists. Thus, it seems that the view is being redrawn despite no changes in variables. I'm seeking advice on what situations to be suspicious of.

Comment: Put static data to `selection` e.g. `.constant(0)` and to `options` .e.g [0, 1, 2, 3 ...], is this still happening or not? Using directly Singleton for `options` is not a good option. You better use `@StateObject` to get the data from `ItemsInformation.shared.getItems(customer, category: category)` and then use the data from viewModel.

Comment: Please give a complete minimal reproducible example with object model and data.

Comment: I suspect it's the `ForEach(options, id:\.self)` initializer. I'd propose to require `T` to conform to `Identifiable`, then use `ForEach(options)` initializer.

Comment: I tested it in a static variable state using constant(0) and Array(0..<100), but the same phenomenon occurred.

Comment: I also tried requiring Generic T to conform to Hashable & Identifiable before using ForEach, but the same symptom persists. What's peculiar is that it works fine in other views, but encounters the issue only in this specific view. Despite the absence of any special variable updates or Timers in this particular view, the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I want to express my gratitude to those who offered advice.

I am using the following View to formalize the list format.

```swift
struct SampleList<T: Identifiable, Content: View>: View
{
    @Binding var datas: [T]
    let attributes: [ListTextAttribute]
    let row: (T) -> Content
    
    var width: CGFloat
    {
        return self.attributes.reduce(0){$0 + $1.width}
    }
    
    init(rows: Binding<[T]>,
         attributes: [ListTextAttribute],
         @ViewBuilder customRow: @escaping ((T) -> Content))
    {
        _datas = rows
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.row = customRow
    }
    
    
    var div: some View
    {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .frame(height: 2)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            // header
            HStack(spacing: 0)
            {
                ForEach(self.attributes)
                {   attribute in
                    attribute.getTextRow()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: width, height: 40)
            
            // list
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false)
            {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0)
                {
                    ForEach(datas)
                    {   data in
                        
                        row(data)
                        div
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: width)
        }
    }
}
```

In the given code, I'm unsure of the exact cause, but there seems to be continuous redraws occurring due to the values in the `attributes` within a specific view.

As a solution, I've refactored the view that utilizes this list into a new `Struct: View` and invoked it so that redraws only happen within the view corresponding to that list.

If there are any possible reasons that come to mind regarding this issue, I'd appreciate it if you could share them. Thank you

**+ I apologize for the unclear question earlier.**